# PHP Script for States to Abbreviations Not Working Correctly

Tags: php, state, abbreviation

I'm not sure what's wrong with this script.  When I run it it only gives me the first letter of the abbreviation.

I didn't write the abbreviation part, I found that online.  The only parts of the script that are mine are the GET and Includes.

I've set the state variable to a state and I still get the same thing so I know it's not my portion of the code.  If anyone knows what the issue is please let me know.

Here is the updated code as suggested.  Still having the same problem.

```
$state = 'Alabama';

function convert_state($name, $get = 'abbr') {
$states = array(
'Alabama'=>'AL',
'Alaska'=>'AK',
'Arizona'=>'AZ',
'Arkansas'=>'AR',
'California'=>'CA',
'Colorado'=>'CO',
'Connecticut'=>'CT',
'Delaware'=>'DE',
'Florida'=>'FL',
'Georgia'=>'GA',
'Hawaii'=>'HI',
'Idaho'=>'ID',
'Illinois'=>'IL',
'Indiana'=>'IN',
'Iowa'=>'IA',
'Kansas'=>'KS',
'Kentucky'=>'KY',
'Louisiana'=>'LA',
'Maine'=>'ME',
'Maryland'=>'MD',
'Massachusetts'=>'MA',
'Michigan'=>'MI',
'Minnesota'=>'MN',
'Mississippi'=>'MS',
'Missouri'=>'MO',
'Montana'=>'MT',
'Nebraska'=>'NE',
'Nevada'=>'NV',
'New Hampshire'=>'NH',
'New Jersey'=>'NJ',
'New Mexico'=>'NM',
'New York'=>'NY',
'North Carolina'=>'NC',
'North Dakota'=>'ND',
'Ohio'=>'OH',
'Oklahoma'=>'OK',
'Oregon'=>'OR',
'Pennsylvania'=>'PA',
'Rhode Island'=>'RI',
'South Carolina'=>'SC',
'South Dakota'=>'SD',
'Tennessee'=>'TN',
'Texas'=>'TX',
'Utah'=>'UT',
'Vermont'=>'VT',
'Virginia'=>'VA',
'Washington'=>'WA',
'West Virginia'=>'WV',
'Wisconsin'=>'WI',
'Wyoming'=>'WY'
);
if($get == 'name') {
// in this case $name is actually the abbreviation of the state name and you want the full name
$states = array_flip($states);
}

return $states[$name];
}
```

Comment: I'd change your algorithm.  You're wasting a hash table by doing a manual search.  It's like buying a Porsche, then pushing it everywhere.

Comment: Change it to what?  I'm a novice with PHP.

Comment: If you're a novice with PHP then you should start by reading the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an excellent answer to this question already, but since the OP is still having problems with this, here's an alternate solution.  Please note that the array $a2s needs to be fully populated, as I only added two states to keep this short. Save the following to the file of your choice (eg: state.php):

```
<?php
$state = $_GET['state'];
echo convert_state($state);

function convert_state($key) {
    $a2s = array( 
        'AL'=>'Alabama',
        'CA'=>'California'
    );
    $array = (strlen($key) == 2 ? $a2s : array_flip($a2s));
    return $array[$key];
}
?>
```

To run the above, you'd type one of the following in your browser (assuming your file is state.php):

```
state.php?state=AL
state.php?state=Alabama
```

The code is designed to work either way.

Answer (score 3):

You should refactor your `$states` as:

```
$states = array(
  'Alabama' => 'AL',
  'Alaska' => 'AK',
  [...]
);
```

Then your function becomes:

```
function convert_state($name, $get = 'abbr') {
  $states = [.. see above ..];

  if($get == 'name') {
    // in this case $name is actually the abbreviation of the state name and you want the full name
    $states = array_flip($states);
  }

  return $states[$name];
}
```

Comment: Ok I tried that and I'm still having exactly the same problem.  I make $state = 'Alabama'; and I get A when I echo $state['abbrev'];

Comment: If you read my code well, you'll see that there is no `abbrev` key in the `$states` array. In fact, `echo $states['Alabama']` will print `AL`, which is the correct abbreviation. If you have `$state = 'Alabama'` then you'd need to `echo $states[$state]`!

Comment: I tried states['state'] and get nothing.  If I use state['state'] I get an A. $states['Alabama'] I get nothing.

Comment: I cannot understand what you're doing wrong, but it would seem you'd need to freshen on how PHP arrays work: it is obvious that `$states['state']` produces nothing since the `$states` array has no `state` key! Could you please update your question with details of the new code you're testing?

Comment: Ok updated it.  I'm a novice with php so it just may be some simple error on my part.