# Display State abbreviation based on IP location using codehelper.io

Tags: javascript, php

Has anyone ever used the codehelper.io.php script to get users location based on ip?
If so, can someone please help me figure out how I can echo each state abbreviation.

For example:

New York = NY

California =  CA

```
<?php
 // Required Libraries
  require_once("ip.codehelper.io.php");
  require_once("php_fast_cache.php");

      // New Class
    $_ip = new ip_codehelper();

  // Detect Real IP Address & Location
  $real_client_ip_address = $_ip->getRealIP();
  $visitor_location       = $_ip->getLocation($real_client_ip_address);

 // Output result
 echo $visitor_location['Country']."";
 echo $visitor_location['RegionName'];
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that without setting up your own mapping from RegionName to the 2 digit US state code.

Here are the elements returned from the IP address using this class.

```
IP
ContinentCode
ContinentName
CountryCode2
CountryCode3
Country
CountryName
RegionName
CityName
CityLatitude
CityLongitude
CountryLatitude
CountryLongitude
LocalTimeZone
REMOTE_ADDR
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
CallingCode
Population
AreaSqKm
GDP_USD
Capital
Electrical
Languages
Currency
Flag
```

Comment: mm ok. i guess i can try to set up a php script that converts the state to abbreviation.

Comment: Or use a config file with array.

Comment: Yea, giving it a try. Something like this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728188/php-script-for-states-to-abbreviations-not-working-correctly?rq=1